# Binomial transform of Dirchlet series (2)

Tags: cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Referring to this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362906/binomial-transform-of-dirichlet-series/362929#362929), i managed to do the following :

We denote by $J(k+1,z)$ the sum :
$$J(n+1,z)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}\binom{n}{k}\frac{\theta(k+1)}{(k+1)^{z}}$$
and by $S(k+1,z)$ the sum :
$$S(n+1,z)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\theta(k+1)}{(k+1)^{z}}$$
After some algebra, we obtain :
$$J(n+1,z)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}\binom{n+1}{k+1}S(k+1,z)$$
Thus :
$$\Phi(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}\binom{n+1}{k+1}S(k+1,z)$$
Using the notation in the aforementioned question, and a variant of Perron's formula, we have :
$$S(k+1,z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i }\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\Theta(s+z)\frac{(k+1+\delta)^{s}}{s}ds$$
Where $\Re(z)>\beta-c,\;\;\;\;c>0,\;\;\;\;0<\delta<1$.

Ignoring issues of convergence (not justified), we have :
$$\Phi(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i }\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\Theta(s+z)\frac{f(s)}{s}ds\;\;\;\;\;(A)$$
Where we define:
$$f(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}\binom{n+1}{k+1}(k+1+\delta)^{s}$$
To take a concrete example, consider the [globally convergent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Globally_convergent_series) for the Riemann zeta function :
$$\zeta(z)-\frac{1}{z-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|G_{n+1}|\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}\binom{n}{k}(k+1)^{-z}$$
Where $G_{n}$ are the [Gregory coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_coefficients). Now, we have (needs some work) :
$$f(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|G_{n+1}|\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}\binom{n+1}{k+1}(k+1+\delta)^{s}=\frac{1}{s+1}\left((1+\delta)^{s+1}-\delta^{s+1}\right)=\int_{\delta}^{1+\delta}x^{s}dx$$
Thus, according to the formulae above, we have :
$$\zeta(z)-\frac{1}{z-1}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\int_{\delta}^{1+\delta}\zeta(s+z)\frac{x^{s}}{s}dxds\;\;\;\;\;(B)$$
But :
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i }\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\zeta(s+z)\frac{x^{s}}{s}ds=\sum^{'}_{n\leq x}n^{-z}$$
Where the dash on the summation symbol indicates that the term $n = x$, if it occurs, is to be halved. Plugging this in the integral above doesn't yield the LHS !! And i must have done something wrong. I am almost certain that the interchange of the integral and summation in (A) is the source of the error. However, we have that :
$$\sum^{'}_{n\leq x }n^{-z}=\zeta(z)-\zeta(z,1+\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor)$$
Where $\zeta(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the Hurwitz zeta function. And we have :
$$\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0^{+}}\int_{\delta}^{1+\delta}(\zeta(z)-\zeta(z,1+x))dx=\zeta(z)-\frac{1}{z-1}$$
In other words, inserting the 'smooth part' of $\zeta(z)-\zeta(z,1+\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor)$ in B yields the correct answer ! there is an element of truth to my approach !

**My question** : What have i done wrong ? and how can we rectify the situation ?